# What's the purpose of overwriting __new__ here?

Tags: python

I was reading the code for the Python `intervaltree` module and saw the following code, ([source code here](https://github.com/chaimleib/intervaltree/blob/master/intervaltree/interval.py)):

```
class Interval(namedtuple('IntervalBase', ['begin', 'end', 'data'])):
    __slots__ = ()  # Saves memory, avoiding the need to create __dict__ for each interval

    def __new__(cls, begin, end, data=None):
        return super(Interval, cls).__new__(cls, begin, end, data)
```

It doesn't seem to do anything extra in the `__new__` function, so what is the purpose of overwriting it here?

Any help will be really appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: See that default value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parent class is:

```
namedtuple('IntervalBase', ['begin', 'end', 'data'])
```

The parameters `begin`, `end`, and `data` are all *required* parameters here.

In `Interval`, the argspec has changed: the `data` is now *optional* and defaults to `None`.

Comment: Ohh! I see! Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps consider adding an explanation as to why overriding `__init__` is not good enough in this case. Otherwise, this answer hits the nail on the head.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I would consider that somewhat irrelevant/orthogonal to the question. Overriding `__new__` is typical for immutable types such as tuples.